# Rails - Print html to printer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I print HTML formatted text to selected printer in Rails? Is there a gem or a ruby code that allows this?

For example:

1- I have 3 printers installed in linux: 'printer_a', 'printer_b' and 'printer_c'.

2- I have a layout `toprint.html.erb`

3- I want Rails, instead of rendering `toprint.html.erb` to the client's browser, to send the HTML page to be printed by `printer_b` for example.

The problem is that I can't find a way that Rails would do this for me

Comment: Most modern printed stuff is done by printing HTML pages. Assuming that's what you're using Rails for (you know, web services), look for articles on print stylesheets.

Comment: Is your question "how to print to a specific printer?" or "how to print the HTML format the way I see it in my browser?"

Comment: @lacostenycoder both

Comment: @josh-brody the articles I'm finding are related to use Rails to render an HTML page that can be used for printing in the client's side. What I need is for the server to print HTML formatted text to a printer attached to the server itself

Comment: Can you provide some context and example of what you have tried that didn't work.  What is supposed to trigger printing? Where does the HTML come from?

Comment: @lacostenycoder I've updated the question to explain it better

Comment: What OS is the server running on? You may be able to use system commands to find the printers and then select which one to print from, and then use another system command to send the print itself.

Comment: @JoshBrody I'm using Ubuntu 14. I believe I'll end up having to do this way...